# How do I write an if statement to check if a style attribute contains nothing?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, dom, javascript-objects, dom-events

I'm trying to make a functionality where if I click a span that is not struck through, it will become so and vice versa. I tried making an if statement that would give the exact value for the attribute the is returned when using    `console.dir(x)`. In the case of textDecoration, I get `textDecoration:""`. How would I be able to reflect this in an id statement?

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("span")

for(var i=0; i<x.length;i++){

    x[i].addEventListener("click", function(){

        if(this.style.textDecoration=""){

            this.style.textDecoration="line-through"
        }
        else{

            this.style.textDecoration=""
        }
})
}
```

Edit: As it stands when I click the span, nothing happens.

Comment: What's wrong with what you have?

Comment: if(this.style.textDecoration="")
This is an assignment, not a comparison. Use === operator for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're observing is because you're using `=` in your if statement (assignment) instead of `==` or `===` (equality check).

### However

A better solution would be to add a new class rule in your CSS file:

```
.lineThrough {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

And then in your JavaScript file, just toggle the class:

```
var x = document.querySelectorAll("span");

for(var i=0; i<x.length;i++){
    x[i].addEventListener("click", function(){
        this.classList.toggle("lineThrough");
    });
}
```

Don't mix presentation in your logic.